# check min value for all unique entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
datetime                    id
2020-01-22 11:57:09.286 UTC 5
2020-01-22 11:57:02.303 UTC 6
2020-01-22 11:59:02.303 UTC 5
```

I want to create a new data set out of it such that for each unique  id, the minimum date time value is selected. So, for example, out of the first and third rows, the third row is deleted while the first one stays. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort `datetime` in ascending order then keep the first duplicates value in `session_id` column.

```py
df = df.sort_values('datetime', ascending=True).drop_duplicates('session_id', keep='first')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this :

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df = df.groupby('session_id').agg({'datetime':  min}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby()` on session_id and extract minimum datetime of each group using `min()`

```
df = df.groupby("session_id")["datetime"].min().reset_index()
```

Comment: Can this be modified that any additional corresponding columns are also added to the final output?

Comment: You will have to apply aggregation function to other columns too in order to have them in final output.